# How can I send messages from my Qt GUI Window to another process

Tags: c++, qt, process, stdin, qprocess

I want to make an editor for my OpenGL application. The OpenGL application executes by itself and creates its own window using the SDL2 library. I've made a Qt widget GUI, and I start QProcess by clicking a button, which starts the OpenGL application on the left:

[image]

I've read about how to send messages to the other process, and although I'm not sure if this is the ideal way to do it I decided to try and write into the standard input of the OpenGL app from the Qt GUI window. So upon clicking a button in the GUI I have code that goes:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{// engineProcess is a pointer to the OpenGL QProcess started earlier.

    const char* ch = "Hello";
    engineProcess->write(ch, 5);
    // engineProcess->writeData()
}
```

Then in my OpenGL app I try each update:

```
fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
int num = ftell(stdin);
if (num > 0)
    GUI::OSDlog.addLogEntry("input");
```

My understanding being that this does a check whether the standard input for the OpenGL app is empty or not. However, no input gets added ever. I don't know what to do.

If I use char ch = getchar() and the input is empty the OpenGL app will stop until there is something in the stdin, this is why I'm checking.

Also, I don't know if this is the best way of sending messages to the process. If there is a better way, please let me know.

Comment: What about using socket?

Comment: ^ Or a named pipe?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look them up.

Comment: Worker thread doing `getchar` or better `getline`.

Comment: Pass `\n` 0xD symbol at the end of message in your stdout/stdin interaction and accept it via getline. Basically do putline/ getline and not even explicit `\n` required.

Comment: If you are going to send a lot of (binary) data consider [zeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/), we had pretty good experience with it. If you are OK with lower amounts of textual data Qt has pretty good support for WebChannels which will give you easy two-way communication via [QWebChannel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-index.html) and there are more than decent WebChannel libraries for any language.

Comment: So far I've had about 5 suggestions all of which (as far as I know)  are different. I thought it would be rather simple to communicate between two windows/processes, I guess either through the Qt framework or WinAPI. Thanks for the suggestions, I've got a lot reading up to do.